# whats wrong with this php script? (generating an html snippet for a select field)

Tags: php, html

Mid afternoon mental block. Simple PHP script to generate an HTML snippet. Will appreciate a second pair of eyes to spot what I'm doing wrong ...

```
<?php $prevname = ''; ?>
<?php foreach($subcategories as $sub_category): ?>
    <?php $newname = $sub_category->getCategory()->getName(); ?>
    <?php $group_changed = strcmp($newname, $prevname); ?>
    <?php if ($group_changed): ?>
    <optgroup label="<?php echo $newname; ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $sub_category->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $sub_category; ?></option>
    <?php if ($group_changed): ?>
    </optgroup>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**[Edit]**

Generated HTML looks like this:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Group1">
            <option value="1">Group1 Sub Item 1</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group1">
            <option value="2">Group1 sub Item 2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <!-- and so on ...
</select>
```

instead of what I expected:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Group1">
            <option value="1">Group1 Sub Item 1</option>
            <option value="2">Group1 sub Item 2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group2">
            <option value="1">Group2 Sub Item 1</option>
            <option value="2">Group2 sub Item 2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <!-- and so on ...
</select>
```

Comment: What goes wrong? What does the generated HTML look like and what's wrong with it? :)

Comment: Why are you wrapping each line of code with `<?php ... ?>` tags?

Comment: You're not HTML entity encoding your output for starters ... but I doubt that's your main problem :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $group_changed = (strcmp($newname, $prevname) != 0) ; ?>
```

And you are not assigning $prevname to the $newname.

Additionally, the optgroup should be closed not in the same iteration, but on next optgroup name change. The code should look something like this:

```
<?php $prevname = ''; $group_opened = false; ?>
<?php foreach($subcategories as $sub_category): ?>
    <?php $newname = $sub_category->getCategory()->getName(); ?>
    <?php $group_changed = (strcmp($newname, $prevname)!=0) ; ?>
    <?php if ($group_changed): $prevname = $newname;?>
           <?php if ($group_opened):?>
             </optgroup>
           <?endif; ?>
    <optgroup label="<?php echo $newname; ?>">
     <?php $group_opened = true; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $sub_category->getId() ?>"><?php echo $sub_category; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I suspected it would be something as silly as that. I suspect you are on the right track .... the strcmp expression should boolean evaluate correctly - the problem is that I failed to reassign newname as you correctly spotted. I'll check and accept your answer if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I've tried rewritting the code, check it and let me know if this resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes, as I suspected. all I had to do was to assign the $newname value. SMH. I can't believe I missed that (too much partying lastnight - and I pay the price ...)

Comment: Don't forget to close the final optgroup.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing the `select` tag.

Check out your generated HTML on a browser. It should be something like:

```
<select name="c">
  <optgroup label="8.01 Physics I: Classical Mechanics">
    <option value="8.01.1">Lecture 01: Powers of Ten</option>
    <option value="8.01.2">Lecture 02: 1D Kinematics</option>
    <option value="8.01.3">Lecture 03: Vectors</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Code sample from [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/optgroup).

Answer (score 0):

As there are two groups to be rendered

1 - optgroup
2 - option

So you have to write two foreach loops, one inside another, kinda like

```
foreach () {
print '<optgroup>...';

foreach () {
print '<option>...';
}
}
```